# Populate hierarchical structure data with jQuery and sqlite

Tags: jquery, html, sqlite, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have some data in table parents_relations. 
I'm trying to populate in an array (arrayCollect) all the ids are inside the tree structure.
 My main question is how to fire the endd() function after all the event queries finish.
Is that possible with Deferreds?

the tables

```
persons table
persons_id  | Name 
---------------------
1       |   Name1       
2       |   Name2       
3       |   Name3   
4       |   Name4   
5       |   Name5   
6       |   Name6   
7       |   Name7   
8       |   Name8   
9       |   Name9   
10      |   Name10  
11      |   Name11  
12      |   Name12
13      |   Name13
14      |   Name14
15      |   Name15

parents_relations table
p_r_id  | contacts_id | parent_contacts_id
-----------------------------------------
1       |   11      |   3
2       |   11      |   4
3       |   3       |   1
4       |   3       |   2
5       |   9       |   3
6       |   9       |   4
7       |   8       |   1
8       |   8       |   2
9       |   5       |   1
10      |   5       |   2
11      |   4       |   14
12      |   4       |   15
```

starting deferred

```
var startItem = {
        p_r_id: '',
        contacts_id: '',
        parent_contacts_id: '11'
    };

    var arrayCollect = [];
    var temp = [];
    temp.push(startItem);
    $.when(builder(temp))
        .done(function(dt){
              endd();
            console.log(arrayCollect);
    });
```

this is the recursive function

```
    builder = function ( items) {
    var deferB     = $.Deferred();
    deferArr.push(deferB);

    if (items.length > 0) {
        $.each(items, function (index, persn) {
                arrayCollect.push(persn);
                $.when(sqlGet_Parents(persn.parent_contacts_id, li)

                ).done(function(ret) {
                    deferB.resolve(ret);
                    builder(ret)
                }).fail(function(){ 
                    alert("$.when(html5db.webdb.sqlGet_Parents.... failed!"); 
                });
        });
    } else { 
        deferB.resolve();
    } 
    return deferB.promise();
}
```

This is the Query function

```
sqlGet_Parents = function(idd) {
    var deferB     = $.Deferred();
    var selectOk = function (transaction, results) {
        var arrids = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
            arrids.push(results.rows.item(i));
        }
        deferB.resolve(arrids);
    },
    selectFail = function() {
        var arrr = [];
        deferB.reject(arrr);
    };
    var db = html5db.webdb.db;
    db.transaction(function(tx){
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * from parents_relations WHERE contacts_id = ? ',
        [idd],
        selectOk,
        selectFail
        );
    });
    return deferB.promise();
}

function endd(){ 
   console.log(arrayCollect);
   alert('Finaly!!!');
}
```